# How do you sum the result of call-template in XSLT?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got some XML as follows;

```
<risk>
  <driver driverId="2">
    <vehicleUse>M</vehicleUse>
  </driver>
  <driver driverId="3">
    <vehicleUse>F</vehicleUse>
  </driver>
  <driver driverId="4">
    <vehicleUse>I</vehicleUse>
  </driver>
</risk>
```

I am using XSLT (v1.0, .NET implementation) to translate each vehicleUse into a number, and then get the total of those numbers. The vehicleUses are translated as M=3, F=2 and I=1. An added complexity is that for the driver with an ID of 3, those values are multiplied by 10, and for driver 4 by 100. So in the example above the total would be 3 + 20 + 100 = 123.

I've defined a template in my XSLT file like this;

```
<xsl:template name="getVehicleUseScore">
  <xsl:param name="driverId" />
  <xsl:param name="vehicleUse" />
  <!-- Implementation left out for brevity -->
</xsl:template>
```

The remainder of the XSLT file then calls the template;

```
<xsl:template match="risk">
  <vehicleUseScore>
    <xsl:for-each select="driver">
      <xsl:call-template name="getVehicleUseScore">
        <xsl:with-param name="driverId" select="@driverId" />
        <xsl:with-param name="vehicleUse" select="vehicleUse" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </vehicleUseScore>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

The result is that I get the text "320100" which is just 3, 20 and 100 concatenated together, which does at least prove that the getVehicleUseScore template works.

I'd like to pass the results of getVehicleUseScore into the sum() function but I don't know how. I tried the following;

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(getVehicleUseScore(@driverId, vehicleUse))" />
```

But the XSLT compiler states "getVehicleUseScore() is an unknown XSLT function".

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you're on .net, then you could be using XSLT 2.0, in the shape of Saxon or XMLPrime. Then you wouldn't need to ask the question, because with XSLT 2.0 such things are dead easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a short XSLT 1.0 way to do this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="risk">
  <vehicleUseScore>
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfResult">
        <xsl:for-each select="driver">
          <xsl:call-template name="getVehicleUseScore">
            <xsl:with-param name="pdriverId" select="@driverId" />
            <xsl:with-param name="pvehicleUse" select="vehicleUse" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(msxsl:node-set($vrtfResult)/*)"/>
  </vehicleUseScore>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="getVehicleUseScore">
  <xsl:param name="pdriverId" />
  <xsl:param name="pvehicleUse" />
  <score>
   <xsl:variable name="vValue" select=
   "(($pvehicleUse='M')*3 + ($pvehicleUse='F')*2 + ($pvehicleUse='I')*1)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vFactor" select=
   "1 +(9*($pdriverId=3)) + (99*($pdriverId=4))"/>

   <xsl:value-of select="$vValue*$vFactor"/>
  </score>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<risk>
    <driver driverId="2">
        <vehicleUse>M</vehicleUse>
    </driver>
    <driver driverId="3">
        <vehicleUse>F</vehicleUse>
    </driver>
    <driver driverId="4">
        <vehicleUse>I</vehicleUse>
    </driver>
</risk>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<vehicleUseScore>123</vehicleUseScore>
```

**Explanation**:

When capturing the output of a template in a variable, this variable is of type RTF (Result Tree Fragment), and unless it's content contains any node (except a text node) its content cannot be navigated by XPath expressions.

To do this, a vendor - dependent extension function `xxx:node-set()` needs to be called on that variable, so that it converts the RTF into a regular tree.

Here we also use the fact that whenever a boolean is encountered in an arithmetic expression, it is converted to number, and that by definition:

```
number(true()) = 1
```

and

```
number(false()) = 0
```

Comment: I used your XSLT but it produced a result of zero. I adjusted it so that each call to getVehicleUseScore was wrapped in a  driverScore element, then adjusted the sum to work like this           <xsl:value-of select="sum(msxsl:node-set($vrtfResult)/driverScore)" /> I wonder if the problem is related to the vendor-specific implementation of node-set. Nonetheless, thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: @gilles27 His solution should work. His has the `getVehicleUseScore` template itself returning the values wrapped in `<score>`. Perhaps the difference was that you used your own implementation of that template that didn't do that? I do think it makes sense to have `getVehicleUseScore` return just a value instead of an element with a value in it. If I were to use this approach, I would add a template like `<xsl:template match="driver" mode="score"><driverScore><xsl:call-..... /></driverScore></xsl:template>` and replace the `for-each` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="driver" mode="score" />`.

Comment: Yes I think that probably was the problem. In any case I've got the result I wanted, plus learned a bit more about XSLT, so thanks to both of you

Comment: @gilles27, You are welcome. The problem you had is in modifying this solution "too much". Please, be assured that I always test a transformation and verify it is producing the wanted result. I actually copy the actual result from the transformation and paste it into the answer.

Comment: Guilty as charged, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

One more approach that's a bit more lenghty but avoids the use of the `node-set()` function (I like to avoid proprietary functions when possible, even though `node-set()` is only *semi* proprietary) is to use recursion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="risk">
    <vehicleUseScore>
      <xsl:call-template name="sumDriverScores">
        <xsl:with-param name="drivers" select="driver" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </vehicleUseScore>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="sumDriverScores">
    <xsl:param name="drivers" />

    <xsl:if test="not($drivers)">
      <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$drivers">
      <xsl:variable name="currentValue">
        <xsl:call-template name="getVehicleUseScore">
          <xsl:with-param name="driverId" select="$drivers[1]/@driverId" />
          <xsl:with-param name="vehicleUse" select="$drivers[1]/vehicleUse" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="sumRemainder">
        <xsl:call-template name="sumDriverScores">
          <xsl:with-param name="drivers" select="$drivers[position() > 1]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue + $sumRemainder"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="getVehicleUseScore">
    <xsl:param name="driverId" />
    <xsl:param name="vehicleUse" />
    <xsl:variable name="useFactor" select="translate($vehicleUse, 'MFI', '321')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="idFactor" 
                  select="1 + 9 * ($driverId = 3) +  99 * ($driverId = 4)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$useFactor * $idFactor"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<vehicleUseScore>123</vehicleUseScore>
```

Comment: JLRishe, We should avoid using recursion whenever possible. Just try your solution with an XML document containing 1000 or more drivers. Not to speak that a hand-written recursion takes the time of the developer and is vulnerable to commiting errors every time. On another note, the OP has indicated he is using .NET, which means that he *can* use the `msxsl:node-set()` extension function.

Comment: Whilst I agree with Dimitre's observations, this is still a perfectly valid answer, thank you. I'd also not seen the translate function before, which looks very useful.